# Elevator Simulator help in Java

Tags: java, simulation

I'm having trouble finishing a basic elevator simulator in Java. What I have so far is an option that lets the user input whether they want to choose a floor, to pull a fire alarm, or to quit the simulation. When they choose select floor, they can pick any floor from 1 to 100, except 13. What I can't figure out how to do is to get the simulation to track their current floor so that they can go down. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Elevator {

    public Elevator() {}

    public void selectFloor() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int newFloor;

        System.out.println("Enter the floor you'd like to go to ==> ");
        newFloor = scnr.nextInt();
        if (newFloor > 100 || newFloor < 0 || newFloor == 13) {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
        }

        else if (newFloor <= 100 && newFloor > 0 && newFloor != 13) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= newFloor; i++)
                System.out.println("..." + i);
                System.out.println("Ding!");
        }
    }

    public void fireAlarm() {
        System.out.println("Danger, you must exit the building now!");
    }
}
```

Also, would it be helpful to post my other class for this program?

Comment: Can't you add an instance variable for storing the currentFloor?

Comment: try with problems with multiple elevators , person can board any elevator which ever comes first !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Elevator` should have a `currentFloor` field, like so:

```
private int currentFloor;
```

Then, in `selectFloor`, you need to find the direction. Also, in `selectFloor`, the `else if` is unnecessary.

```
public class Elevator {
    private int currentFloor;

    public Elevator() {
        currentFloor = 0;
    }

    public void selectFloor() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int newFloor;

        System.out.println("Enter the floor you'd like to go to ==> ");
        newFloor = scnr.nextInt();
        if (newFloor > 100 || newFloor < 0 || newFloor == 13) {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
        }

        else {  // The if was not necessary
            int direction = 0;
            if(currentFloor < newFloor){
                direction = 1; // going up;
            } else if (currentFloor > newFloor) {
                direction = -1; //going down;
            } else {
                direction = 0; //going nowhere;
            }
            for (; currentFloor != newFloor; currentFloor += newFloor)
                System.out.println("..." + i);
                System.out.println("Ding!");
        }
    }

    public void fireAlarm() {
        System.out.println("Danger, you must exit the building now!");
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this yet, so I can't be sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `Elevator` object a class variable by adding a `private int floor;` directly under the class opening tag. (Above the Elevator class constructor.) This variable will be tied directly to the Elevator object that contains it.

That way when you create your Elevator by using `new Elevator` you'll also have an int value always available to hold the floor. To access this value, build a getter and setter method. They should look like the following:

```
public void setFloor(int floor) {
    this.floor = floor;
}

public int getFloor() {
    return floor;
}
```

You can then call these two methods to set the floor number and get the floor number. To keep track, in your `selectFloor` method you'll need to use setFloor and pass it the floor number after a valid selection is made. You could then use getFloor to determine whether it would be going up or down.

To have your constructor set the `floor` variable at 1 when a new Elevator object is created. Simply change your constructor to look like this:

```
public Elevator() {
    setFloor(1);
}
```

Hope this helps! If you have any questions on how those things are working let me know, I'll try to provide more details.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to implement the getFloor and setFloor into my selectFloor method. So far I put setFloor(floor) after floor=scnr.nextInt();, but I'm not sure that works

Answer (score 0):

I just inserted a new method called backToBasement() and tied it into your selectFloor() method. Hope its helpful.

```
public void selectFloor() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int newFloor;

        System.out.println("Enter the floor you'd like to go to ==> ");
        newFloor = scnr.nextInt();
        if (newFloor > 100 || newFloor < 0 || newFloor == 13) {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
        }

        else if (newFloor <= 100 && newFloor > 0 && newFloor != 13) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= newFloor; i++)
                System.out.println("..." + i);
                System.out.println("Ding!");
                backToBasement(newFloor);
        }
    }

    public void fireAlarm() {
        System.out.println("Danger, you must exit the building now!");
    }

    public void backToBasement(int newFloor){
        for (int i=newFloor; i>0;i--){
             System.out.println("..." + i);
        }
        System.out.println("Ding!... Back to Ground Level");

    }
```